Giving a terraformed helm chart key some yaml code
Trying to set the affinity for the keda operator installed by the keda helm chart.
And I can't seem to get terraform to like how I am doing it...
locals {
  affinity_json = {
    "nodeaffinity" : {
      "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution" : {
        "nodeSelectorTerms" : [
          {
            "matchExpressions" : [
              {
                "key" : "karpenter.sh/capacity-type",
                "operator" : "NotIn",
                "values" : ["spot"],
              }
            ],
          }
        ],
      },
    }
  }
  affinity_yaml = <<-EOF
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: karpenter.sh/capacity-type
          operator: NotIn
          values:
          - spot
EOF
}


resource "helm_release" "keda" {
  name       = "keda"
  repository = "https://kedacore.github.io/charts"
  chart      = "keda"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.keda.metadata.0.name
  version          = "2.14"
  create_namespace = false
  # uninstall: https://keda.sh/docs/2.14/deploy/#helm

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.operator.name"
    value = "keda"
  }
  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.operator.create"
    value = "false"
  }
  set {
    name  = "operator.affinity"
    value = jsonencode(local.affinity_json)
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_service_account.keda_service_account, kubernetes_namespace.keda]
}

The issue is with the key setting for operator.affinity.
I tried several ways to get the value into that key.
value = jsonencode(local.affinity_json)

(error from terraform, no apply)

Error: failed parsing key "operator.affinity" with value {"nodeaffinity":{"requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":{"nodeSelectorTerms":[{"matchExpressions":[{"key":"karpenter.sh/capacity-type","operator":"NotIn","values":["spot"]}]}]}}}, key "]}]}}}" has no value

value = local.affinity_json
(error from terraform, no apply)

Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.

value = local.affinity_yaml
(error from terraform attempt to apply)

Error: cannot patch "keda-operator" with kind Deployment:  "" is invalid: patch: Invalid value: ...lots of json...
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field PodSpec.spec.template.spec.affinity of type v1.Affinity


value = yamlencode(local.affinity_yaml)
(error from terraform attempt to apply)

Error: cannot patch "keda-operator" with kind Deployment:  "" is invalid: patch: Invalid value: ...lots of json...
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field PodSpec.spec.template.spec.affinity of type v1.Affinity

And I can't seem to get anything to work.

I gave up.  Nothing worked.  guess you just can't do that.  Moved to putting the info in a values.yml file and feeding that to the helm_release resource.  kinda lame, but we do what we gotta do.
